# ZF2 Restful hierarchical routes

Tags: php, rest, routes, zend-framework2, hierarchical

I'm trying to use a hierarchical resource in ZF2 for a Restful API. The resource should looks like `clients/1/addresses`. What I've tried was this

```
'clients' => array(
    'type' => 'segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/clients[/:id]',
        'constraints' => array(
            'id'     => '[0-9]+',
         ),
         'defaults' => array(
             'controller' => 'Api\Controller\ClientController',
         ),
     ),
     'may_terminate' => true,
     'child_routes' => array(
         'addresses' => array(
             'type'    => 'segment',
             'options' => array(
                 'route'    => '/addresses[/:address_id]',
                 'constraints' => array(
                     'address_id'     => '[0-9]+',
                 ),
                 'defaults' => array(
                      'controller' => 'Api\Controller\AddressController',
                  ),
              ),
          ),
      ),
  ),
```

There is this conflict of both id's, but I don't know if I rename the route identifier `id` of the resource addresses like I did will solve it. Anyway, the real problem is that the route `clients/1/addresses` calls the `get` method of the `AddressController`, not the `getList`, and I think that's because Zend understands that the id of the client belongs to addresses, so its calls the get method.

Do you know how to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably right that `get` is called instead of `getList` because of the `id` being present in your route match parameters and [the controller by default uses `'id'` for matching the route identifier](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/blob/master/src/Controller/AbstractRestfulController.php#L45).

The way to deal with this is that you give the route identifiers names that fit the resource. So for client you make `client_id` and for address you use `address_id` (like you already did).

And then you configure your `AbstractRestfulController` instance to "look" for the correct route identifier [using the `setIdentifierName` method](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/blob/master/src/Controller/AbstractRestfulController.php#L65):

```
$clientController->setIdentifierName( 'client_id' );

$addressController->setIdentifierName( 'address_id' );
```

This is just an example, the best way to do this is (of course) by using a controller factory...